# Matplot Lib Loop through dataframes and add subplots to figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame with 7 columns of categorical information that I would like to loop through for each columns unique labels and count of rows per label, that would then be added as a bar chart subplot to my figure. I am able to create a figure with the correct amount of subplots for the figure and also the individual DataFrames with column name and counts, but I'm not sure how I can return a new subplot to the figure from each cycle in the loop. Any help of the proper process? Provided is my attempt below and error message at the loop:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

**Libraries**

```
# Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
%matplotlib inline
```

**Categorical DataFrame (df_cat)**

df_cat = example data from `.head()` method
[image: head]

**Figure and amount of subplots**

```
plt_nrows = round(len(df_cat.columns) / 2)
plt_ncols = len(df_cat.columns) - sub_plt_rows

fig, axs = plt.subplots(plt_nrows, plt_ncols, figsize=(20,15))
```

**Loop of DataFrames with individual columns and label counts:**

```
for i in df_cat.columns:
    df_cat_counts = df_cat[i].value_counts().rename_axis([i]).reset_index(name='counts')
    x = df_cat_counts[i]
    y = df_cat_counts['counts']
    axs[i,0].plot(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am limiting myself to columns ['Age', 'Directors', 'Genres', 'Country', 'Language'], because imdb, rotten tomatoes, and netflix are something that imho is not really categorical data.

```
import itertools

# split?
split_dict={'Directors':',',
       'Genres':',',
       'Country':',',
       'Language':','}

columns = ['Age', 'Directors', 'Genres', 'Country', 'Language']


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

for p, col in enumerate(columns):

    ax = fig.add_subplot(2,3,p+1)

    split = split_dict.get(col)

    if split: # split individual cells by the resp. string. unfold and flatten using chain.from_iterable
        x = pd.Series(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df_cat[col].dropna().str.split(split))).to_frame(name=col)
    else:
        x = df_cat[[col]]

    x.groupby(col).apply(len).plot(kind='bar',ax=ax)

    split=None
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I am going for. I tried applying this logic to my code, but the output of `plt.tight_layout()` is `<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>` and no figure is shown.

Comment: My comment above is if that command is run in a separate cell in Jupyter. When run together I get a bunch of error messages after a long time of running. All along similar lines of `RuntimeWarning: Glyph 2332 missing from current font.  font.set_text(s, 0.0, flags=flags)`

Comment: @cphill plt.tight_layout() is only needed to adjust the subplot spacing. The error you are getting seems to have something to do with your data. Can you post a representative sample of your data that you can reporduce this error with?

Comment: Yes, I actually noticed a more complete error message `Tight layout not applied. tight_layout cannot make axes height small enough to accommodate all axes decorations`. The dataset is hosted on Kaggle at https://www.kaggle.com/ruchi798/movies-on-netflix-prime-video-hulu-and-disney?select=MoviesOnStreamingPlatforms_updated.csv

Comment: @cphill to be honest, I would rather not register at kaggle. Can you copy+paste a subset of the data?

Comment: Not a problem. Hosted the csv here: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/1bf4b9055ad20feaca7aea71f3e62810/data.csv

Comment: @cphill see my edit. Did this for the first 100 entries.